# Can a Flame game object such as PositionComponent be Collidable and Draggable

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

Successfully implemented a `Draggable` component. When adding the `Hitbox` and `Collidable` mixins to the class extended by `PositionComponent` the drag functionality stops working.

Is it possible to have a draggable component that is also collidable?

Flutter version: 2.2.3
Flame version: 1.0.0-releasecandidate.13

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'DraggablesGame.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    GameWidget(
      game: DraggablesGame(),
    ),
  );
}
```

**DraggablesGame.dart**

```
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'DraggableSquare.dart';

class DraggablesGame extends BaseGame with HasDraggableComponents, HasCollidables {

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    add(DraggableSquare());
    add(DraggableSquare()..y = 350);
  }
}
```

**DraggableSquare.dart**

```
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/extensions.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flame/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' show Colors;
import 'DraggablesGame.dart';

class DraggableSquare extends PositionComponent
    with Draggable, HasGameRef<DraggablesGame>, Hitbox, Collidable {
  @override
  bool debugMode = true;

  DraggableSquare({Vector2? position})
      : super(
    position: position ?? Vector2.all(100),
    size: Vector2.all(100),
  );

  Vector2? dragDeltaPosition;
  bool get isDragging => dragDeltaPosition != null;

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    super.update(dt);
    debugColor = isDragging ? Colors.greenAccent : Colors.purple;
  }

  @override
  bool onDragStart(int pointerId, DragStartInfo info) {
    dragDeltaPosition = info.eventPosition.game - position;
    return false;
  }

  @override
  bool onDragUpdate(int pointerId, DragUpdateInfo event) {
    final dragDeltaPosition = this.dragDeltaPosition;
    if (dragDeltaPosition == null) {
      return false;
    }

    position.setFrom(event.eventPosition.game - dragDeltaPosition);
    return false;
  }

  @override
  bool onDragEnd(int pointerId, _) {
    dragDeltaPosition = null;
    return false;
  }

  @override
  bool onDragCancel(int pointerId) {
    dragDeltaPosition = null;
    return false;
  }
}
```

### Update based on answer

Spydon's answer suggested using `addHitbox(HitboxRectangle());`. This resulted in the following error:

> The method 'addHitbox' isn't defined for the type 'DraggableSquare'.

Instead this modified constructor allows for both the dragging and colliding.

**Updated DraggableSquare Constructor**

```
DraggableSquare({Vector2? position})
      : super(
    position: position,
    size: Vector2.all(100),
  ) {
    final hitBox = HitboxRectangle();
    addShape(hitBox);
  }
```

Comment: Please share the code of your component

Comment: @spydon code added. The dragging works until Hitbox and Collidable are added as mixins.

Comment: @spydon Hoping to make the example easier to understand. I updated the example code to use the official documentation code. When adding the two mixins to the official example, the squares are no longer draggable. Is it possible to use both `Draggable` and `Collidable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the `Hitbox` mixin you also have to add some hitboxes, otherwise it will not be able to know what it should count as a "hit".
The simplest solution is to add an empty hitbox of either the `HitboxRectangle` or `HitboxCircle` type. These hitbox will will the full size of the component if you don't define anything more specific in them.

So to add a `HitboxRectangle`, you modify your constructor to this:

```dart
  DraggableSquare({Vector2? position})
      : super(
          position: position ?? Vector2.all(100),
          size: Vector2.all(100),
        ) {
    addShape(HitboxRectangle());
  }
```

If you set `debugMode = true` you will be able to visually see the hitboxes that you add.

Comment: Left an update at the bottom of the question. `addHitbox` results in an error. Might be due to the version of Flame being used? I shared the working constructor changes. If you can modify your answer I can mark as correct. And thanks for the Flame support!

Comment: Ah right, it is called `addHitbox` in `rc14` which will be released in a few days or so. No problems! I would recommend joining our discord for faster support (link can be found on the website).